# AWS iot dynamodb rule ${value} NoSuchElementException

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-iot

I'm trying to set an AWS IOT rule to send data to DynamoDB without the help of a lambda.

My rule query statement is : `SELECT *, topic() AS topic, timestamp() AS timestamp FROM '+/#'`

My data is fine in AWS IOT as I'm successfully retrieving it with a lambda. However, even by following [the developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-ddb-rule.html) to create the rule, in order to get the information passed on to Dynamo, by setting the 2 form fields with ${topic} and ${timestamp} as it should work, I get nothing in DynamoDB and I can find the following exception in Cloudwatch :

`MESSAGE:Dynamo Insert record failed. The error received was NoSuchElementException. Message arrived on: myTopic/data, Action: dynamo, Table: myTable, HashKeyField: topic, HashKeyValue: , RangeKeyField: Some(timestamp), RangeKeyValue:`

HashKeyValue and RangeKeyValue seem to be empty. Why ?

I also posted the question on the AWS forum : https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=267987

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your devide sends this payload:

```
mess={"reported": 
{"light": "blue","Temperature": int(temp_data)),
"timestamp": str(pd.to_datetime(time.time()))}}
```

args.message=mess

You should query as:

```
SELECT message.reported.* FROM '#'
```

Then, set up DynamoDB hash key value as ${MessageID()}

You will get:

MessageID || Data

```
1527010174562    { "light" : { "S" : "blue" }, "Temperature" : { "N" : "41" }, "timestamp" : { "S" : "1970-01-01 00:00:01.527010174" }}
```

Then you can easily extract values using Lambda and send to S3 via Data Pipeline or to Firehose to create a data stream.